# Slide Toggle JQuery not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, slidetoggle

So I got it working just fine on the first page I tried it on:

http://www.uksf.net/platoon.php

but I cannot make it work on the front page:

http://www.uksf.net/index.php (the navigation bars on the side are supposed to have that little menu drop down (you can see on the inspector)).

here is the code:

```
        $this->con = $this->connect();

    $query = $this->con->prepare('SELECT * FROM SideNav WHERE type = "top" ORDER BY displayorder ASC');
    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $query->execute();

    while ($row = $query->fetch()){
        echo'<div class="sn'.$row["id"].'">';
        echo'<div class="sidelink">'.
            $row["name"].'
            </div>';

        $query2 = $this->con->prepare('SELECT * FROM SideNav WHERE type = "bottom" AND parent = :id ORDER BY displayorder ASC');
        $query2->bindParam(':id', $row["id"]);
        $query2->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $query2->execute();
        $rot = $query2->fetch();
        if(!empty($rot))
        {
            echo'<div class="sn'.$row["id"].'group">';
            echo'<div class="sidelinksub">';

            $query2 = $this->con->prepare('SELECT * FROM SideNav WHERE type = "bottom" AND parent = :id ORDER BY displayorder ASC');
            $query2->bindParam(':id', $row["id"]);
            $query2->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $query2->execute();
            while ($row2 = $query2->fetch()){
                echo'<div>'.
                $row2["name"]
                .'</div>';
            }
            echo'</div></div>';
        }
        echo'<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".sn'.$row["id"].'").click(function(){
                $(".sn'.$row["id"].'group").slideToggle("slow");
                });
            });</script></div>';
    }
```

The slide toggle doesn't work I have spent a few days trying to fix this so I haven't come on a whim, help appreciated thanks.

Comment: This might be helpful: `http://www.uksf.net/js/slideShow.js 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 0):

Your toggle seems OK but you have some JS errors. Try to use the developers tools (press F12 on chrome).

I suggest to use a more generic function for the toggeling. **[See example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ks39R/)**

```
$(function(){
    $("div.hide").hide();
    $("div.menu").click(function(event){
        $("#" + event.target.id + "group").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

This function have a recursion problem:

```
function slideNext($slidePos, $slides, $captions) {
    if($slidePos != 2) {
        $slidePos = $slidePos + 1;
    }
    else {
        $slidePos = 0;
    };
    $nextLeft = $slidePos * -690;
    $slides.delay(5000).animate({left: $nextLeft}, 1000);
    $captions.delay(5000).animate({left: $nextLeft}, 1000);
    slideNext($slidePos, $slides, $captions);
};
```

The last line is being call too many times. you get `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error.

As I can see you call this function with `$slidePos = 0` and then if it's not equals 2 you set the value to 0 again. In any case you keep calling the `slideNext` function, regardless of your state. This means you don't have a stop condition.

Comment: This is made by the other chap working on the site, it is acting on the slide show not my slide toggle. My slide toggle still won't slide

Comment: You can see nothing happens when clicking it

Comment: Of course it doesn't work, the script is stuck before you even clicking, only when you fix the first problem you'll be able to see if your toggle script works. By the way - you should include the JQuery script only once, and you should write a more generic function to handle the click and not generate function for each button. See my suggestion in the updated answer